# android volley not sending response when app is closed

Tags: android, android-volley

hi have created a volley program it work fine when my app is running...  but when app is close the data is post to server but it don't give response... from the server the code goes this way... i have put all my code and This run in Intent service so please let me know where its going wrong or whats the problem in volley
.

```
  public class CapitalService extends IntentService{
    NetworkInfo networkInfo;
    Intent mServiceIntent;
    Context context = this;
    public CapitalService(){
        super("Empty Constructor");     
    }
    public CapitalService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        makeJsonObjectRequest();            
    }      
    private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
                "", obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            response.getString("success");

                            final NotificationManager mgr=
                                (NotificationManager)CapitalService.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                            Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.add_more,
                                                                            "Android Example Status message!",
                                                                            System.currentTimeMillis());

                            // This pending intent will open after notification click
                            PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(CapitalService.this, 0,
                                                                    new Intent(CapitalService.this, Home.class),
                                                                    0);

                            note.setLatestEventInfo(CapitalService.this, "Android Example Notification Title",
                                                    "This is the android example notification message", i);

                            mgr.notify(2133, note);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                });
        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }


}
```

Comment: If the app is closed and killed there won't be any callbacks to get the response from the server. Maybe you should consider using a Service that will run in background whether your app is running or not. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: i am calling this volley in service

Comment: @arthur_gg i have edited my above code do have a look

Comment: can you show the declaration of the service in your manifest? I think you need to specify android:process=":myService" so the service won't use the same process as the activity and won't be killed.

Comment: <service 
            android:name=".CapitalService"
            android:exported="false" />

Answer (score 1):

**onHandleIntent** is a thread also , So you can put your code in **onHandleIntent** without any function, so you code should be like below:

```
public class CapitalService extends IntentService{
NetworkInfo networkInfo;
Intent mServiceIntent;
Context context = this;
public CapitalService(){
    super("Empty Constructor");     
}
public CapitalService(String name) {
    super(name);
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

              JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
            "", obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        response.getString("success");

                        final NotificationManager mgr=
                            (NotificationManager)CapitalService.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.add_more,
                                                                        "Android Example Status message!",
                                                                        System.currentTimeMillis());

                        // This pending intent will open after notification click
                        PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(CapitalService.this, 0,
                                                                new Intent(CapitalService.this, Home.class),
                                                                0);

                        note.setLatestEventInfo(CapitalService.this, "Android Example Notification Title",
                                                "This is the android example notification message", i);

                        mgr.notify(2133, note);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
```

}

or you can use **asycktask** Like This:

```
    @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String user_id = prefs.getString("user_id", "");
        String last_1 = prefs.getString("last_id_general_news", "");
        String last_2=prefs.getString("last_id_local_news", "");
        String last_3=prefs.getString("last_id_events", "");
        String last_4=prefs.getString("last_id_gas", "");
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user_id));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cat_1", last_1));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cat_2",last_2));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cat_3",last_3));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cat_4", last_4));


        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(RestClient.URL_NOTIFICATION, params);

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("request");
        int len = jsonArray.length();
        if (len > 0) {             
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                JSONObject newsObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // if(!newsObj.toString().equals("{}")){

                if (newsObj.getString("news_category_id").equals("1")) {
                    NatureItemGeneralNews natureItemGeneralNews = new NatureItemGeneralNews();

                    natureItemGeneralNews.setId(Integer.valueOf(newsObj.getString("news_id")));
                    natureItemGeneralNews.setTitle(newsObj.getString("news_title"));
                    natureItemGeneralNews.setDate(newsObj.getString("news_updated_at"));
                    natureItemGeneralNews.setImgUrl(newsObj.getString("news_attachment"));
                    natureItemGeneralNews.setSubject(newsObj.getString("news_text"));
                    List<NatureItemGeneralNews> temp = new ArrayList<NatureItemGeneralNews>();

                    boolean exist=false;
                    for (NatureItemGeneralNews n : MainActivity.ListForGeneralNews) {
                        if(n.getId()==natureItemGeneralNews.getId()){
                            exist=true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!exist) {
                        temp.add(natureItemGeneralNews);
                    }


                    for (NatureItemGeneralNews n : MainActivity.ListForGeneralNews) {
                        temp.add(n);

                    }
                    MainActivity.ListForGeneralNews = new ArrayList<>(temp);
                    MainActivity.LastIdGeneralNews = natureItemGeneralNews.getId();
                    Last_Id_General=natureItemGeneralNews.getId();

                    SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs1.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_id_general_news",natureItemGeneralNews.getId()+"");
                    editor.commit();


                    if(!exist) {
                        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
                        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
                        int icon = R.mipmap.ic_lunch;
                        CharSequence tickerText = natureItemGeneralNews.getSubject();
                        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MyAlarmService.this, PageOfNew2.class);
                        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_id", natureItemGeneralNews.getId() + "");
                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_title", natureItemGeneralNews.getTitle());

                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_updated_at", natureItemGeneralNews.getDate());
                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_attachment", natureItemGeneralNews.getImgUrl());
                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_text", natureItemGeneralNews.getSubject());
                        notificationIntent.setAction("myString" + requestID);

                        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyAlarmService.this, requestID, notificationIntent, 0);
                        notificationIntent.setData((Uri.parse("mystring" + requestID)));
                        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, natureItemGeneralNews.getTitle(), "", contentIntent);

                        notification.flags += Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
                        notification.flags += Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                        Uri notification1 = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification1);

                        r.play();
                        mNotificationManager.notify(NOT_ID_1, notification);
                    }

                } else if (newsObj.getString("news_category_id").equals("2")) {
                    NatureItemLocalNews natureItemLocalNews = new NatureItemLocalNews();
                    natureItemLocalNews.setId(Integer.valueOf(newsObj.getString("news_id")));
                    natureItemLocalNews.setTitle(newsObj.getString("news_title"));
                    natureItemLocalNews.setDate(newsObj.getString("news_updated_at"));
                    natureItemLocalNews.setImgUrl(newsObj.getString("news_attachment"));
                    natureItemLocalNews.setSubject(newsObj.getString("news_text"));
                    natureItemLocalNews.setCityName(Temp.getCityName(Integer.valueOf(newsObj.getString("news_city_id"))));
                    List<NatureItemLocalNews> temp = new ArrayList<NatureItemLocalNews>();


                    boolean exist=false;
                    for (NatureItemLocalNews n : MainActivity.ListForLocalNews) {
                        if(n.getId()==natureItemLocalNews.getId()){
                            exist=true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!exist) {
                        temp.add(natureItemLocalNews);
                    }



                    for (NatureItemLocalNews n : MainActivity.ListForLocalNews) {
                        temp.add(n);
                    }
                    MainActivity.ListForLocalNews = new ArrayList<>(temp);
                    MainActivity.LastIdLocalNews = natureItemLocalNews.getId();
                    Last_Id_Local=natureItemLocalNews.getId();


                    SharedPreferences prefs1 =getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs1.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_id_local_news", natureItemLocalNews.getId()+"");
                    editor.commit();


                    if(!exist) {
                        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
                        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
                        int icon = R.mipmap.ic_lunch;
                        CharSequence tickerText = natureItemLocalNews.getSubject();
                        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MyAlarmService.this, PageOfNew2.class);
                        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_id", natureItemLocalNews.getId() + "");
                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_title", natureItemLocalNews.getTitle());

                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_updated_at", natureItemLocalNews.getDate());
                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_attachment", natureItemLocalNews.getImgUrl());
                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_text", natureItemLocalNews.getSubject());
                        notificationIntent.setAction("myString" + requestID);
                        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyAlarmService.this, requestID, notificationIntent, 0);
                        notificationIntent.setData((Uri.parse("mystring" + requestID)));
                        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, natureItemLocalNews.getTitle(), "", contentIntent);
                        notification.flags += Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
                        notification.flags += Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                        Uri notification1 = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification1);

                        r.play();
                        mNotificationManager.notify(NOT_ID_2, notification);
                    }

                } else if (newsObj.getString("news_category_id").equals("3")) {
                    NatureItemEvents natureItemEvents = new NatureItemEvents();
                    natureItemEvents.setId(Integer.valueOf(newsObj.getString("news_id")));
                    natureItemEvents.setTitle(newsObj.getString("news_title"));
                    natureItemEvents.setDate(newsObj.getString("news_updated_at"));
                    natureItemEvents.setImgUrl(newsObj.getString("news_attachment"));
                    natureItemEvents.setSubject(newsObj.getString("news_text"));
                    natureItemEvents.setCityName(Temp.getCityName(Integer.valueOf(newsObj.getString("news_city_id"))));


                    List<NatureItemEvents> temp = new ArrayList<NatureItemEvents>();
                    boolean exist=false;
                    for (NatureItemEvents n : MainActivity.ListForEvents) {
                        if(n.getId()==natureItemEvents.getId()){
                            exist=true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!exist) {
                        temp.add(natureItemEvents);
                    }

                    for (NatureItemEvents n : MainActivity.ListForEvents) {
                        temp.add(n);
                    }
                    MainActivity.ListForEvents = new ArrayList<>(temp);
                    MainActivity.LastIdEvents = natureItemEvents.getId();
                    Last_Id_Event=natureItemEvents.getId();

                    SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs1.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_id_events", natureItemEvents.getId()+"");
                    editor.commit();


                    if(!exist) {
                        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
                        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
                        int icon = R.mipmap.ic_lunch;
                        CharSequence tickerText = natureItemEvents.getSubject();
                        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MyAlarmService.this, PageOfNew2.class);
                        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_id", natureItemEvents.getId() + "");
                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_title", natureItemEvents.getTitle());

                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_updated_at", natureItemEvents.getDate());
                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_attachment", natureItemEvents.getImgUrl());
                        notificationIntent.putExtra("news_text", natureItemEvents.getSubject());
                        notificationIntent.setAction("myString" + requestID);
                        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyAlarmService.this, requestID, notificationIntent, 0);
                        notificationIntent.setData((Uri.parse("mystring" + requestID)));
                        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, natureItemEvents.getTitle(), "", contentIntent);
                        notification.flags += Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
                        notification.flags += Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                        Uri notification1 = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification1);

                        r.play();
                        mNotificationManager.notify(NOT_ID_3, notification);
                    }

                } else if (newsObj.getString("news_category_id").equals("4")) {
                    NatureItemGasSatation natureItemGasSatation = new NatureItemGasSatation();
                    natureItemGasSatation.setNameGasStation(newsObj.getString("gas_station_name"));
                    natureItemGasSatation.setAddress(newsObj.getString("gas_station_address"));
                    String date = newsObj.getString("gas_station_date");
                    String date1 = date.substring(5);
                            natureItemGasSatation.setDate(newsObj.getString("gas_station_date"));
                    natureItemGasSatation.setDate(date1);
                    natureItemGasSatation.setId(Integer.valueOf(newsObj.getString("gas_station_id")));

                    List<NatureItemGasSatation> temp = new ArrayList<NatureItemGasSatation>();
                    boolean exist=false;
                    for (NatureItemGasSatation n : MainActivity.ListForGasStation) {
                        if(n.getId()==natureItemGasSatation.getId()){
                            exist=true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!exist) {
                        temp.add(natureItemGasSatation);
                    }

                    for (NatureItemGasSatation n : MainActivity.ListForGasStation) {
                        temp.add(n);
                    }
                    MainActivity.ListForGasStation = new ArrayList<>(temp);
                    MainActivity.LastIdGasStation = natureItemGasSatation.getId();
                    Last_Id_Gas=natureItemGasSatation.getId();

                    SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs1.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_id_gas", natureItemGasSatation.getId()+"");
                    editor.commit();


                    if(!exist) {
                        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
                        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
                        int icon = R.mipmap.ic_lunch;

                        CharSequence tickerText = "new notification";
                        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MyAlarmService.this, MainTabActivity.class);
                        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        notificationIntent.setAction("myString" + requestID);
                        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyAlarmService.this, requestID, notificationIntent, 0);
                        notificationIntent.setData((Uri.parse("mystring" + requestID)));
                        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "كازيات", "", contentIntent);
                        notification.flags += Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
                        notification.flags += Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                        Uri notification1 = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification1);
                        r.play();
                        mNotificationManager.notify(NOT_ID_4, notification);
                    }
                }

                       }// if null
            }// for


        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```